# SqlDependency & OnChangeEventHandler discovering what data has changed?

Tags: sql-server, wpf, windows, wcf

When using SqlDependency & OnChangeEventHandler in .Net with SQL Server, is it possible (simple?) to discover what data has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the query again and compare the result obtained with the previous result. How simple it is to detect exactly what changed, depends on what exactly you SELECTed (a single row, all rows in a table, a subset of rows, an aggregate on some/all rows, a join between several tables etc etc). But in general is not simple at all, and is always best to simply run the entire query again, discarding the previous result.

Think at Query Notifications as a means to actively invalidate caches, not as a mean to track changes.

Comment: Thanks, I have a single source of data updates, so I can track them on that end, and possibly do comparisons. However, I think it would probably be best to just refresh the SELECT request for that client.

Comment: If you don't use `Take` or `Skip` you can hide this behind a Linq2SQL query: http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/

Comment: FYI I'd be connecting (from the client) to the result set on the remote server, and then internally on the client app doing a Skip/Take to show paged results (but the total list would be fairly small) I assume this won't affect using `linqtocache` (which I'd use to connect the initial full result set)

Comment: If you use Skip/Take on the IEnumerable *after* the results were cached then it should be OK, as long as the result set is reasonable size.